# How to get char to be null?

Tags: c, null, char

So This is what I wrote to test the windows subsystem for ubuntu:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int () {
     char a = '\0';
     printf("H%cello World\n",a);
     return 0;
}
```

I compiled it, then ran the program. It shows:

```
 USER@DESKTOP-blahblah~/dir/%./a.out
 H ello World
```

????

Screenshot for reference:
https://gyazo.com/c25c4214f00e90c8e123f45e84ca1964

EDIT:::

I expected

```
 USER@DESKTOP-blahblah~/dir/%./a.out
 Hello World
```

Comment: what did you expect?

Comment: I expected Hello World

Comment: Why did you expect that?

Comment: And what the NUL terminating char?

Comment: Could i set char a to something so that it prints hello world instead of H ello World?

Comment: If you are stupid or not we don't care, try to change the question to *How to get **char** to be **null***

Comment: @CarlosAbraham Ok

Comment: `int ()` should be `int main()`, or, better, `int main(void)`. You obviously didn't make that mistake on your system; if you had, your program wouldn't have compiled and you could never have gotten any output. Always copy-and-paste your exact source code into the question. Don't make us guess which errors are actually in your program and which you introduced when you re-typed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 char a = '\0';
 printf("H%cello World\n",a);
```

`a` is a null character, not an empty character. In fact there's no such thing as an empty character. The `printf` call will print `H`, followed by a null character, followed by `"ello World"`, followed by a newline character.

On my system (Ubuntu, xterm), when I run your program (after fixing it) I see:

```
Hello World
```

because I happen to be using a terminal emulator that ignores null characters. You apparently are using one that either prints a space or just advances the cursor when you print a null character.

No, there's no value to which you can set `a` that will cause your program to print just `Hello World`.

If you wanted to modify your program to use an empty *string* (which does exist) rather than an empty *character* (which doesn't), you could:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
     char empty[] = "";
     printf("H%sello World\n", empty);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm writing a helper function that loops through every variable to check for '\0' 's.

Comment: Re "*In fact there's no such thing as an empty character*", Sure there are. They are called zero-width space. U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE serves to mark places where it's acceptable to insert a break, and U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE is commonly used as a Byte Order Mark (BOM).

Comment: @ikegami: Depends on what you mean by "empty". Not all display devices will necessarily treat those characters consistently, and if you write such a character to a file or pipe the program's output through something like `cat -A` or `hexdump` it will show up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no empty char as you are thinking. NUL terminating char is not an empty `char`. It is a character with an ascii code of `0`. You have printed the NUL terminating char. And it is not outputting space - it is simply printing the `'\0'`. It might be something else on different systems.